# Integrating custom view without a model into admin

Tags: django-admin, django-views

I'm trying to figure out how to integrate a given view into the admin url scheme without manually setting up the url.

Background:
I have three models for which I get data in one CSV file (don't even ask why...). So the import view is not bound to a given model in my concept.

Is there any way to register a view without a model to the default admin site, so that I can add the view to the sidebar block in app_index with an url relative to the app (like "app/import")?

I would like to avoid writing the "admin/app/import" url to my urlconf. However, if that can't be avoided, could someone give me some tips how to at least make them portable? (like variables containing the apps name/base url for the app admin)

I don't know all the magic behind django yet.